# Vim with powerline is extremely slow with a few buffers open

Tags: macos, vim, tmux

I'm using OS X Yosemite, and with Powerline installed, scrolling on terminal Vim becomes extremely slow with just 2-3 buffers open -- there's a half-second lag or so between scrolling and the redrawing catching up.

I used the installation instructions [here](http://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/osx.html). This happens with both iTerm2 and Terminal, both with and without tmux. I'd appreciate any help! I would like to keep Powerline, but this slowness is unbearable.

Comment: I would say *dump that useless plugin* but that wouldn't really help so I'll say *go ask on powerline's issue tracker* instead.

Comment: @romainl or use [airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) instead.

Comment: thanks guys; I ended up using airline. making powerline faster is probably more trouble than it's worth.